# Who was the most powerful asura in history

Tags: vedas, gods, asuras, manuscripts, demi-god

I want to know if there is any asura who is touted to be the most powerful of all. Like top tier asura.

Comment: Hiranyakashipu and Hiranyaksha were very powerful. Hiranyaksha submerged the entire planet earth into the cosmic ocean.

Comment: Has to be Bali. Hands down.

Comment: Madhu Ketabh were also immensely powerful, undefeated by Vishnu.

Comment: this is opinion based..also, it should be more focused... Indrajita was most powerful in Ramayana era as per Uttara kanda..but it's too hard to define for all eras combined..

Comment: this is one of the opinion based questions I would totally allow on this site. Should be fun to see which asura has biggest fan following :) @YDS

Comment: @mar "most powerful" is bit ambiguous. I love it when answers surpass other answers, and we see at least 10 answers-one beating the other. I think the question here doesn't include any quantitative quality.